# Converting a project from C to Java

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-ndk

I am currently messing around with Android beginning to make an app. The application connects with a bluetooth device, then sends it signals, then the other device sends back the data that was requested.

I was given documentation for the other devices API written in C, which basically stores all the specific signals needed to send the device. How can I change these from C files to java files. I have downloaded the Android NDK but don't know what to do with it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can call the C library from your Android Java code, (if i understood you correctly this is what you wanted to do). 
You will need NDK and will need to use JNI to allow the java code to talk to the c library.
There are plenty of good tutorials on these just search.

For example
[Marakana has a good tutorial/video on Android internals](http://marakana.com/s/andevcon_android_internals,271/index.html). Take a look at the part where he talks about building applications with JNI support. He uses example of a library in C that calculates fibonacci sequence but he calls that library from Java.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what I'm talking about, only because I want to use a custom project that is written in C, not a default library of C.

Comment: And also that video is far too long for me to sit through to find what i want :P thanks though

Comment: @user1435712 I think that you need to create an API for the C project which can then be called from Java.